# if condition in if block not being checked

Tags: java, swing

So basically the values from database are fetched and displayed in JTable. I wanted a popup to appear if one of the fields contain a value. For example , I want that if the section_name in JTable is "Executive Summary" then a popup should appear. But what I find is that the if condition in line 12 gets executed even if the section_name is not "Executive Summary".This is the if block that I am referring to:-

```
if (section_name.equals("Executive Summary"));
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "it works", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
                }
```

The popup displays each time. Where lies the error and how should it be corrected.

```
 ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                section_name = rs.getString("Section_Name");
                report_name = rs.getString("Report_Name");
                contact_name = rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                link = rs.getString("Link");
                String m="apple";
                model.addRow(new Object[]{section_name, report_name, contact_name, link,m});
                i++;
            }
           if (section_name.equals("Executive Summary"));
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "it works", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
            }
            if (i < 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: Where's line 12? I can count, but it's probably a lot easier for answerers if you put the line explicitly in your question

Comment: @user3580294 : I've edited my question. I hope it is now clear to you ! :-)

Comment: Yep! Just something to keep in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
if (section_name.equals("Executive Summary"));
```

Make it:

```
if (section_name.equals("Executive Summary"))
{
    ....
}
```

By leaving the semi-colon in, it make's it the equivalent of:

```
if (section_name.equals("Executive Summary")) {}
{
    .... /* always executed */
}
```

Comment: OH my GOD ! How couldn't I see it ! feel so ashamed ! :-)

Comment: I'm just glad I caught it. These things normally go right over my head :)

Comment: @user3608233 It might be possible to configure your IDE to format your code so that this kind of thing is caught. Mine is configured to always put braces after `if` statements, so something like that would be saved as `if (condition) { ; }`, with the semicolon and ending brace on new lines. That kind of thing is *really* hard to miss.